# There are $3{,}684{,}030{,}417$ different semigroups of order $8$.

Tags: combinatorics, semigroups

Early on in *"Nine Chapters on the Semigroup Art,"* by Alan J. Cain it is claimed that

> there are $3{,}684{,}030{,}417$ different (non-isomorphic) semigroups with $8$ elements.

How was this number reached?

Comment: [According to Peter Cameron](https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/discrete-mathematics-and-big-data-summary/), "These numbers are not just evaluations of a formula: essentially the objects must be generated and counted". So it seems the answer to your question would be: by brute force enumeration.

Comment: [This PhD thesis](https://research-repository.st-andrews.ac.uk/handle/10023/945) might explain things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found yourself an important reference. You may also read the following articles:

[1] Andreas Distler and Tom Kelsey. The monoids of orders eight, nine & ten. *Ann. Math. Artif. Intell.*, **56**(1):3–21, 2009.

[2] Andreas Distler and Tom Kelsey. The semigroups of order 9 and their automorphism groups, *Semigroup Forum* **88**(1):93–112,
2014.

[3] S. Satoh, K. Yama, and M. Tokizawa. Semigroups of order 8. *Semigroup Forum*, **49**(1):7–29, 1994.